# How to create a login for a table in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

Need help to create a login in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio for a table

Comment: Please, describe what you want to accomplish more precisely.

Comment: i want to connect my database with visual studio so for that purpose i want to create a login script

Comment: [How to create a login script in MS sql server managment studio 2008 for connection with visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470663/how-to-create-a-login-script-in-ms-sql-server-managment-studio-2008-for-connecti)??

Comment: You cannot create a login for a *table* - only for an entire *database* ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must understand that security in SQL is a huge piece to be summarized in a short response.
But since your question is very vague, I'll answer in an schematic way.

If I understand you correctly, you have to

- to create a new user in the SQL server instance.
  you have the UI to do this in SSMS | **Object Explorer window | Security | Logins** right click **new user**.
- go thru the different tabs: general to set a user name and other connection options, Server role (probably you'll only need to keep public), and User Roles to give access to the minimum specific database.
- once you have the user, you can give access to the given table. SSMS | **Object Explorer window | Databases | [your database] | Security | [the new user]** *right click | properties*. choose **securables** and **Search**

Comment: Thanks Luis...Please can u help me how i connect my sql server with visual?

Comment: @Sunny I think you are asking for tutorials on SQL, I can't teach SQL Server by Stackoverflow. If you installed SQL in your computer you should have to write down the SA password during the process. If you are trying to access an instance that is at some other server the owner of it will need to provide access. anyway I suggest starting by installing SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Express is for free) and then look for SQL tutorials. Good luck